# How to refresh 'max_user_connections' when building an API Server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, express, phpmyadmin

I am creating a server using Nodejs on Cloud Hosting. When I receive API requests from clients using POSTMAN, the server dies after just 3 - 4 calls.

Upon checking PHPAdmin, I found that the 'max_user_connections' database variable is set to 30. I need help to prevent the server from crashing when getting or posting data.

Comment: Before going into the solution, we need to understand what ```max_user_connections``` does. This is a MySQL system variable that limits the maximum number of simultaneous connections for a single MySQL user account. If the number of active connections exceeds this limit, the server refuses additional connections for this user. It's important to note that this is per-user and not per-application. If multiple applications use the same MySQL user to connect, they all share the same limit.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You say "the server dies," but which server and which service/daemon on that server? What is in the error logs for that specific application? What is showing you that MySQL/MariaDB is the problem? Does your application use the database, and if so what kind of queries are run?